# MomentJS date format as "2017-04-06T13:53"

Tags: momentjs

Would like to convert date time value as following format

2017-04-06T13:53

Thank you

Comment: Please read the docs https://momentjs.com/docs/

Comment: What have you tried so far? Did you read the [docs](https://momentjs.com/docs/)? Which is your input? See how to give [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Question doesn't indicate any effort whatsoever by the OP.  Stack Overflow is not a code writing service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
// Exactly your time format
console.log( moment().format( 'YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm' ) );

// ISO8601 format
console.log( moment().format() );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```